# How to addSubview to the bottom of view hierarchy

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview-hierarchy

I want to add mapView, which I'm adding programatically, to the bottom of hierarchy view, as I already draw some of the elements beforehand, in the storyboard.

So, after i call method:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.map];
```

How do I put it on the bottom of the view hierarchy ?!

Comment: You can use `- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view atIndex:(NSInteger)index`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just put it there directly instead.

```
[self.view insertSubview:_map atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 11):

"This method moves the specified view to the beginning of the array of views in the subviews property."

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:yourView];
```

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 3**

**Swift 4**

`view.insertSubview(view, at: 0)`

Comment: How can you insert it at the absolute bottom of the screen for even the iPhone X (no safe zone)!?

Answer (score 2):

Answer by Robert and rcat24 does work.
Alternatively,

You can use "zPosition"

```
subViewToBeOnTop.layer.zPosition=1.0;

subViewToBeOnBottom.layer.zPosition=.9;
```

1 being top most, 0 being least.